# Adding missing arguments to function pointer in another function

Tags: c++, function, arguments, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have some functions which I would like to call using function pointer. They have different arguments and data types.

```
void processVec2(
    float a, 
    float b, 
    array<vector2> vec2_array, 
    int i, 
    int j)
{
/// some code here    
}
```

```
void processVec3(
    float a, 
    float b, 
    float c,
    float d, 
    array<vector3> vec3_array, 
    int i, 
    int j)
{
/// some code here    
}
```

I want to pass the function inside a loop lunction, and I want to add the loop iteration indices as argument before calling the function which was passed.

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void loopFunction(
    int       iter,
    array<T>  array,
    void (*function)(Args)
    )
{
    // loop on iter
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
    {
        // Loop on input array size
        int arraySize = array.size()
        for(int j = 0; j < arraySize, ++j)
        {
            function(args, i, j) // calling function. I want to pass some arguments and also i and j.
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I want to set the function pointer. However, I don't know how to make it take its variables, and also I cannot set the loop indices variables inside the main function, so both the function pointer's arguments will miss two int.

```
// Main function
void main(
    float          a,
    float          b,
    float          c,
    float          d,
    int            vec2_iter,
    int            vec3_iter,
    array<vector2> vec2_array,
    array<vector3> vec3_array)
{
    // Call loopFunction, passing processVec2 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
    loopFunction<vector2>(vec2_iter, vec2_array, &processVec2(a, b vec2_array));

    // Call loopFunction, passing processVec3 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
    loopFunction<vector3>(vec3_iter, vec3_array, &processVec3(a, b, c, d, vec3_array));
}
```

for the loop function, I only need the _iter, _array, and the function pointer. However, I need to pass arguments from the main function to the function pointer, without explicitly passing them to the loop function.

Is this something possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `loopFunction` to take the additional arguments you want to pass through, expand the parameter pack in the function pointer type and pass the arguments when you call the function pointer:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
void loopFunction(
    int       iter,
    array<T>  array,
    void (*function)(Args..., int, int),
    Args... args
    )
{
    // loop on iter
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
    {
        // Loop on input array size
        int arraySize = array.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < arraySize; ++j)
        {
            function(args..., i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the calling function (note this shouldn't be called `main`) you can't pass the parameters when getting the function pointer and they need to be passed to `loopFunction` directly:

```
// Call loopFunction, passing processVec2 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
loopFunction<vector2>(vec2_iter, vec2_array, &processVec2, a, b, vec2_array);

// Call loopFunction, passing processVec3 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
loopFunction<vector3>(vec3_iter, vec3_array, &processVec3, a, b, c, d, vec3_array);
```

It may be simpler to use lambdas instead:

```
template<typename T, typename Function>
void loopFunction(
    int       iter,
    array<T>  array,
    Function function
    )
{
    // loop on iter
    for(int i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
    {
        // Loop on input array size
        int arraySize = array.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < arraySize; ++j)
        {
            function(i, j);
        }
    }
}

// Call loopFunction, passing processVec2 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
loopFunction<vector2>(vec2_iter, vec2_array, [&](int i, int j){ processVec2(a, b, vec2_array, i, j); });

// Call loopFunction, passing processVec3 as function pointer argument. I need to set the function's argument here too.
loopFunction<vector3>(vec3_iter, vec3_array, [&](int i, int j){ processVec3(a, b, c, d, vec3_array, i, j); });
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't know about lambdas, it works perfectly well for this use case.